# jQuery - get multiple values from the DOM and store in array

Tags: jquery

I have a list of n number of items that can be displayed. Class historyList is for styling, class projYear is only used to get the value.

```
<tr class="uniqueProject">
  <td class="historyList projYear" style="width: 4em;">2011</td>
</tr>
```

Within in this list I can have x number of years. Each new year would repeat the code above. Currently I have 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016. This list will grow over time.

To grab the values within projYear, I have used `$('.projYear').html()`. Unfortunately, this only returns the first on the list of `2011`

**Question:**  How can I use jQuery to place each of the years into an array? (i.e. [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, etc])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy with `.map`

```
var years = $('.projYear').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```